# Does Luton Airport have a blanket ban on unaccompanied minors?

Tags: air-travel, airports, children, ltn, minors

I was told by a member of staff at Luton airport during an emergency redirect of my daughter's flight from Heathrow during heavy snow that children (Unaccompanied minors - UMs) cannot normally fly out of Luton. But I don't know if the staff member was speaking for the airport as a whole, or for their specific airline. Nothing on the Airport website, search or FAQs. The airline I want to use does allow them to fly alone at her age. No mention of Luton in their FAQ either.

Comment: Normally UMs flight is an airline's policy and responsibility.  Not sure how an airport plays into this at all.

Answer (score 2):

I checked london-lutons FAQ's the closest I could find was [special-asistance / wheelchairs](http://www.london-luton.co.uk/en/faq/6/19/how-do-i-book-special-asistance---wheelchairs-etc.html) where they recommend you contact your [carrier](http://www.london-luton.co.uk/en/content/4/158/airline-contact-details.html).